# Confusion about $\mathsf{PA}$'s self-provable consistency sentences

Tags: logic, foundations, peano-axioms, incompleteness

**Edit:** This long question was basically answered by a quick comment! I'll accept an answer if someone posts one, but it's basically answered already.

---

**Background:**

In Peter Smith's *[Introduction to Gödel's Theorems](https://www.logicmatters.net/igt/)* §36.1, he introduces the sentence

$$\mathsf{Prf^\circ(x,y)} =_\text{def} \mathsf{Prf(x, y) \wedge \forall v \leq x \neg Prf(v, \ulcorner \bot \urcorner)}. $$

He then defines

\begin{align}
\mathsf{Prov^\circ(y)} &:= \mathsf{\exists v Prf^\circ (v, y)} \\\\
\mathsf{Con^\circ} &:= \mathsf{\neg Prov^\circ(\ulcorner \bot \urcorner)}
\end{align}

and proceeds to show that $\mathsf{PA} \vdash \mathsf{Con^\circ}$.

Smith's discussion is as follows: *If (and only if!)* $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent, then $\mathsf{Prf^\circ(x,y)}$ expresses proofhood, and hence $\mathsf{Con^\circ}$ expresses consistency. However, if $\mathsf{PA}$ is inconsistent, then $\mathsf{Prf^\circ}$ does *not* express proofhood (this can be seen on a straightforward interpretation of the formula defining $\mathsf{Prf^\circ}$), hence $\mathsf{Con^\circ}$ does not express consistency.

---

**Question Setup:**

I'm not sure if this is a typo, but it seems to me that $\leq$ should be $<$ in the definition of $\mathsf{Prf^\circ}$, since the way it is written, $\mathsf{Con^\circ}$ is trivially provable. In particular

$$\tag{1} \label{con} \mathsf{Con^\circ} = \neg \exists x [ \mathsf{Prf(x, \ulcorner \bot \urcorner) \wedge \forall v \leq x \neg Prf(v, \ulcorner \bot \urcorner)} ]$$

is provable because the part inside the brackets is logically false, which can be seen by taking $\mathsf{v = x}$. Moreover, inspecting $(\ref{con})$ directly, it isn't clear at all whether $\mathsf{Con^\circ}$ actually expresses consistency, even assuming $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent (contrary to the argument given above)—how could a basic logical truth express anything interesting?

So let me define

$$\mathsf{Prf^\star(x, y)} =_\text{def} \mathsf{Prf(x, y) \wedge \forall v < x \neg Prf(v, \ulcorner \bot \urcorner)},$$

with $\mathsf{Prov^\star}$ and $\mathsf{Con^\star}$ defined in the obvious way. It seems to me that $\mathsf{Prf^\star}$ is similar to $\mathsf{Prf^\circ}$ in that it clearly expresses provability if $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent; but at the same time, it seems *better* than $\mathsf{Prf^\circ}$ because the resulting $\mathsf{Con^\star}$ is more than just vacuously true and provable. It seems to express $\mathsf{PA}$'s consistency even without already assuming $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent: $\mathsf{Con^\star}$ says, after all, that there is no "smallest" proof of $\bot$, which is equivalent to saying there is no proof of $\bot$.

---

**Question:**

1. Am I correct that $\mathsf{PA \vdash Con^\star}$?
2. Am I correct that $\mathsf{Con^\star}$ expresses the consistency of $\mathsf{PA}$, without assuming $\mathsf{PA}$'s consistency?

I think the answer to (1) is "yes" because the same argument used by Smith for $\mathsf{Con^\circ}$ goes through for $\mathsf{Con^\star}$. The answer to (2) seems to be "yes" based on the rough argument I gave above. But together, this would imply the unlikely conclusion that $\mathsf{PA}$ simply proves its own consistency, without much room for quibbling about whether the purported consistency statement "counts." What am I missing?

Comment: Why does the same argument that $PA\vdash \sf Con^\circ$go though for $\sf Con^*$? The argument he gives in the version I'm looking at (Thm 36.1) at is the same argument you give that $\sf Con^\circ$ is a trivial logical truth.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Ah, you're right. At first I misunderstood his proof as doing something else. So then, the answer to (1) is "no", presumably?

Comment: Correct. As you remark, $\sf Con^*$ says there is no least proof of inconsistency, which is equivalent to there being no proof of inconsistency... and $\sf PA$ proves this equivalence because it can prove the least number principle. So it's equivalent to $\sf Con$ under $\sf PA$ so can't be proven in $\sf PA$ (unless $\sf PA$ is inconsisent).

Comment: WillG if @spaceisdarkgreen does not wish to post the comment as an answer (which I totally understand, the lack of ability to manage what appears on one's userpage frequently stops me from posting answers), keep in mind that the rules do allow you to self-answer your question. It's better than leaving it in the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reiterate the comments, 2 is correct, but 1 is not. The author's argument that $\sf PA\vdash Con^{\circ}$ is essentially the same as your argument that $\sf Con^{\circ}$ is a trivial logical truth and doesn't transfer to $\sf Con^\star.$ And as you say, $\sf Con^\star$ expresses that there is no least proof of inconsistency, so this is provably equivalent to $\sf Con$ in $\sf PA$ as an instance of the least number principle.

So actually, the $\le$ (as opposed to $<$) is crucial. But for that matter, I'm not sure why the author doesn't just use the simpler definition $$\sf Prf^\circ(x,y) := Prf(x,y)\land \lnot Prf(x, \ulcorner \bot \urcorner).$$ Unless I'm missing something, one can show $\emptyset \vdash \sf Con^\circ$, and that $\sf Prf^\circ$ captures and expresses $Prf$ iff PA is consistent, etc. under this simpler definition by similar arguments.

Comment: I think you mean $\emptyset \vdash \textsf{Con}^\circ$, toward the end?

Comment: @WillG Yep, thanks.